# Ajax return what client would see

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome-extension

I am making a chrome extension that checks for a certain word on a site they specify. To do this, I make an Ajax request to get the html. However, this doesn't return the data that I would like, and I am speculating here: it only receives the data before all JS is rendered, or minus things specific to the client. Here is how I'm making the request. Should I change any of the parameters, or is there a better way of receiving that data?

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: "html",
  context: document.body,
  success: function(data) {
    console.log("Success");
  },
  error: function (e) {
    console.log("Error: Not a valid URL.");
  }
});
```

Comment: What are you getting back in `data`?

Comment: @PritamBanerjee http://pastebin.com/hc3bj28J This is the return for this page. Optimally I would like to only check for the text on the site as if I was ctrl+f searching the page.

Comment: @PritamBanerjee It also seems to be returning the exact copy of the page source.

Comment: `var text = $(data).filter('body').text()`; will give you all the text nodes inside the body as a single concatenated string.

Comment: Hi @joelkornbluh, it doesn't seem to return anything ("") from my code.

Comment: ajax/xhr request doesn't run scripts. You'll have to open that page in 1) a new tab and use content script or 2) in an iframe (this will require stripping X-Frame headers via webRequest API).

Comment: Hi @wOxxOm, is there a way to open tabs in a subtle way?